# How to have Multiple Select queries in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello my issue is I do not know how to use select multiple times in a query when searching through a data base. Here is what I have below

```
$statement = $db->query("    SELECT M.name 
                        FROM actors A, roles R, movies M
                        WHERE M.id = R.movie_id AND R.actor_id = A.id AND A.first_name = '$fname' AND A.last_name = '$lname';");
```

Right now this statement works, it is fine. but for another part of my project I would like for it to look like

```
         SELECT ...

         FROM ... 

         WHERE ... = (SELECT ...

                      FROM ...

                      WHERE...)
```

I know that looks bad, but I am a beginner in SQL, and I can't seem to code this without errors. Any tips would be great! If any other information is needed just ask :)
Thank you very much

Comment: What error are you getting when you use that 2nd SQL?

Comment: mainly syntax, like I apparently have too many ")". Again it is because I am very new to this

Comment: RTM http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html

Comment: We need your entire SQL to know where the syntax error is. Or read this - https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can use such constructs as

```
  SELECT something
    FROM sometable
   WHERE column = (SELECT a FROM anothertable WHERE b = constant)
```

or

```
  SELECT something
    FROM sometable
   WHERE column IN (SELECT value FROM anothertable WHERE c = constant)
```

In the first case `column =` the second, inner, SELECT query must return precisely one value.

In the second case `column IN` the inner query may return a bunch of values in one column. It can return no values at all.